# OpenGL - turn around projection

Tags: opengl, math

I try to turn around my gui. I have projection:

```
glm::mat4 my_projection = glm::mat4( 2.0/static_cast<float>(m_window->getSize().x), 0.0, 0.0, -1.0,
                         0.0, 2.0/static_cast<float>(m_window->getSize().y), 0.0, -1.0,
                         0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
                         0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

And shader:

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 pos;
in vec2 UV;
in vec4 col;

uniform vec2 translation;
uniform mat4 my_projection;

out vec2 vecUV;
out vec4 vecColor;

void main()
{   
    vec3 tran_pos = vec3(pos + vec3(translation, 0.0f));
    gl_Position = vec4(tran_pos, 1.0f) * my_projection;
    vecUV = UV;
    vecColor = col;
}
```

And I don't know how to turn around, when I change

```
m_window->getSize().x
```

to

```
-m_window->getSize().x
```

and

```
m_window->getSize().y
```

to

```
-m_window->getSize().y
```

everything disapear. How I can turn around this?

EDIT: (SOLUTION)

```
glm::mat4 my_projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, (float)m_window->getSize().x, (float)m_window->getSize().y, 0.0f);


// Shader:
#version 330 core

in vec3 pos;
in vec2 UV;
in vec4 col;

uniform vec2 translation;
uniform mat4 my_projection;

out vec2 vecUV;
out vec4 vecColor;

void main()
{      
        vec3 tran_pos = vec3(pos + vec3(translation, 0.0f));
        gl_Position = my_projection * vec4(tran_pos, 1.0f);
        vecUV = UV;
        vecColor = col;
}
```

Just use glm function to matrix projection and multiply projection by position.

Comment: when you answer your own question, put it in an answer response, you can select yourself as the answerer.

Comment: Oh, ok, I don't know. thanks for tip